# Cannot import dependency from external repository (Azure Artifact)

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-artifacts, maven-dependency, maven-repository

I am coming to you because it's been almost 5 hours that I am struggling on importing my packaged spring boot application deployed to Azure Artifacts (Maven repository).

I am using intellij IDEA with JDK 11, intellij is able to autocomplete the class that I want to import, but I am getting "symbol not found" anyway.

Here is my setup :
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I already did almost everything that I found on the internet. I invalidated the caches more than 10x times, reinstalled maven and java, deleting the cache, removing all the .m2 directory but nothing changes ..

I also already put the necessary configuration on settings.xml to point to the repository with my Personnal Access Token.

Did I miss something ? I really need to use my package on Azure to build my application.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you by any chance found a solution?

Comment: Difficult to remember it was a long time ago. but from what I think is that my project group id (com.hkhattabi) was the same as the one that I wanted to fetch.  Meaning that it was looking for the class inside my own project instead of the one retrieved from the maven repository. I am not sure because even if it is the same group id, the class should already be in the classpath.